# Trying to understand clipping logic in PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe

I have the following instructions in a deflate stream inside a PDF:

```
1 g
/GS1 gs
0 792 m
0 792 l
f
q
1 i 
0 792 612 -792 re
0 792 m
W n
0 792.06 612 -792 re
W n
```

1. Set color to Gray.
2. Load some external dictionary information
3. Start subpath in `0` `792`
4. Append point in `0` `792`
5. Fill the path.... Why would you like to fill 1 gray pixel?
6. Save graphic stack
7. set smoothness to 1
8. Start a `0` `792` `612` `-792` rectangle subpath
9. Start a `0` `792` subpath.... Why would you override the previous rectangle path?
10. Make the `0` `792` subpath the clipping path and remove the current path.
11. Start a `0` `792.06` `612` `-792` rectangle.
12. Clip the previous rectangle with the previous clipping path `0` `792`?

The problem I have is that I didn't find good examples for how the clipping works. Which path do you clip against? What do you clip against if you didn't have a clipping path before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are right to wonder, much in the excerpt you show makes no sense.

For example your items 3..5 concerning

```
0 792 m
0 792 l
f
```

The PDF specification states on filling paths like that:

> If a subpath is degenerate (consists entirely of one or more points at the same coordinates), the subpath shall be considered to enclose the single device pixel lying under that point; the result is device-dependent and not generally useful.

*(ISO 32000-2, section 8.5.3.3 — Filling)*

---

Your interpretation of

```
0 792 612 -792 re
0 792 m
W n
```

in your items 8..10 is incorrect, though. In particular your assume the last line to

> Make the 0 792 subpath the clipping path and remove the current path.

Actually the `0 792 m` subpath is disregarded and only the `0 792 612 -792 re` rectangle is intersected with the current clip path!

According to the specification clip path intersection works similar to filling

> Subclause 8.5.3.3, "Filling" defines what is inside a path as well as stating rules for closing paths and for degenerate paths. For a given path definition, the same area that would be filled by the f operator is the area that would be used for a clip.

*(ISO 32000-2, section 8.5.4 — Clipping path operators)*

and filling would drop that dangling `0 792 m`.

> Any subpaths that are open shall be implicitly closed before being filled, except that if the last subpath in the path is a single-point open subpath (specified by a trailing m operator), it shall be disregarded and not considered to be part of the path.

*(ISO 32000-2, section 8.5.3.3 — Filling)*

---

Thus your interpretation of

```
0 792.06 612 -792 re
W n
```

in your items 11 & 12

> Clip the previous rectangle with the previous clipping path 0 792?

is slightly off: Actually this rectangle clips the previous clipping path last clipped by the other, nearly identical rectangle. But this hardly makes more sense to do than your original assumption would have.

---

Concerning your explicit question

> Which path do you clip against? What do you clip against if you didn't have a clipping path before?

Here the specification says:

> The initial clipping path shall include the entire page.

*(ISO 32000-2, section 8.5.4 — Clipping path operators)*

Comment: Hi mkl, thanks for this in-depth answer. So if I understood correctly: 0 792 612 -792 re
0 792 m are 2 subpaths in a Path object. Because the `m` one is degenerate I use the previous valid subpath, the rec. The clipping path is the whole page at the beginning so: 0 0 612 792 re gets clipped against 0 792 612 -792 re ,and then clipped against 0 792.06 612 -792 re again?

Comment: *"So if I understood correctly: 0 792 612 -792 re 0 792 m are 2 subpaths in a Path object. Because the m one is degenerate I use the previous valid subpath, the rec."* - Because the m one is merely a single trailing m, you use *only* the previous valid subpath. In general the *whole* path consisting of any number of subpaths would be used for clipping.

Comment: *"The clipping path is the whole page at the beginning so: 0 0 612 792 re gets clipped against 0 792 612 -792 re ,and then clipped against 0 792.06 612 -792 re again?"* - If the whole page 612x792 with the origin in its lower left, yes.